# plotting boxplots of multiple y variables using ggplot2, qplot or others

Tags: r, function, variables, ggplot2

I am searching the way to draw boxplots of many y variables with x=season and function=event. I want to draw many plots all together like:

fist plot: x=season, y=var1 by function=event
second plot: x=season, y=var1, by fuction=event
..

My data looks like as below. Actually, I have a plenty of variables.

.........................................................................

```
    event     season      var1      var2     var3
1  event_free wet.summer 14.193489 16.786347 22.65968
2  event_free       fall  3.209114  9.948187 15.44799
3       event       fall  4.564315 10.647883 34.24658
4       event       fall 20.152646 31.114422 33.04899
5  event_free       fall  3.944427  6.431695 10.27153
6  event_free       fall  9.994351 16.110569 22.73702
7  event_free       fall  3.100501  6.507310 14.37157
8  event_free     winter  2.631117        NA 13.88889
9       event     winter 20.745972 22.629357 29.27042
10      event     winter 15.929737 21.355657 36.45409
11 event_free     winter  7.383920  7.418910 11.85094
12      event     winter 17.011810 20.320714 44.18071
13      event     spring 12.501078 14.260404 39.08531
14      event     spring 26.224773 32.536549 46.90560
```

.........................................................................

I found many ways to plot one y variable combining with a fuction (ex: event, here) using ggplot2 or qplot, but cannot find how to draw multiple plots all together for multiple y variables.
Thanks a lot for your help!!

slim

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it with `ggplot2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Assume your data frame is named dat
dat.m = melt(dat, id.var=c("event","season"))
dat.m$season = factor(dat.m$season, levels=c("winter", "spring","wet.summer","fall"))

# If you want the two levels of event plotted side by side
ggplot(dat.m, aes(season, value, colour=event)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ variable) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.7)
```

[image]

```
# If you want the levels of event to be faceted (plotted in separate panels)
ggplot(dat.m, aes(season, value)) +
  facet_grid(event ~ variable) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what I want! One more please. I have a plenty of variables. How can I give (1) a range of variables that I want to plot together and (2) names of variables that I want to plot together?

Comment: Unless your real data set different than the sample data you provided, all you need to do is melt the data into long format in the same way as above. Can you say more about what, specifically, you're trying to do and supply some sample data if it's different from what you've already supplied?

Comment: I was looking for making a subset directly from the code you provided, but it would be fine simply adding a thing like "dat=mydata[c(7,15:20)] " before applying your code. Thanks a lot, eipi10 for your great help!! :)

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for this nice answer! So there is no other way to do this than melting multiple columns into one? One cannot add multiple boxplots from different columns?

Comment: You can, but it's much clunkier. ggplot is really designed for "long" data, rather than "wide". Here's an example: `ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x="mpg",y=mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x="wt", y=wt)) +
  labs(x="Variable", y="")`. It works, but you need a separate call to `geom_boxplot` for each column, and you need to hard-code the x-axis tick label.